# MySQL PDO resultSet as object list performance

Tags: php, mysql, performance, pdo

I'm using the following code to get records from DB:

```
$stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, MyClass::class);
$resultSet = $stmt->fetchAll();

return $resultSet;
```

This works fine.
However sometimes the PHP class property names and the database field names are different. In this case we make a mapping as follows:

```
$stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$resultSet = $stmt->fetchAll();

foreach ($resultSet as $record) {
    $resultList[] = $this->convertDbArrayToObject($record, MyClass::class, $mapping);
}

return $resultList;
```

where

```
public function convertDbArrayToObject($record, $class, $mapping = null)
{
    $object = new $class();

    foreach ($record as $key => $value) {
        if (array_key_exists($key, $mapping)) {
            $fieldName = $mapping[$key];
            $setterName = 'set' . ucfirst($fieldName);
            $object->$setterName($value);
        }
    }

    return $object;
}
```

The problem is that the second solution is about ~10-20 times slower that is way too much.

Any idea how could we improve the performance?

Comment: Did you try ` PDO::FETCH_FUNC`?

Comment: It is a bit faster really, but only with ~20% which is still too slow. 
Besides this my problem with FETCH_FUNC that I have only column numbers  and not column names (or at least I don't know how to get column names with FETCH_FUNC) and that can cause problems if eg a new field will be added to the table in the middle.

Comment: Why don't you just use column aliases in your query to match the class attributes?

Comment: @PaulSpiegel At first we wanted to avoid rewriting a lot of query with tableName.* syntax and didn't expect such performance degradation.
But now it seems that aliases will be the solution.

Comment: Are all the "setters" similar?  What does one look like?  I am thinking that `$obj->$setter(...)` is costly.

Comment: Use `microtime(true)` around each statement to see which part is the most costly.